# Exception while inserting connecting to database in hadoop mapreduce job

Tags: java, mysql, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a mapreduce job which is suppose to persist data to the MySQL database but it is throwing an exception which is following,

```
 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201501122044_1310_r_000001_0, Status : FAILED
 java.io.IOException  at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.db.DBOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(DBOutputFormat.java:180)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:444)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1642)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
```

This mapreduce job runs over the cluster of 5 nodes and I have confirmed that database connection is getting formed by testing simple main class with sql connection creation.

I am badly stuck at this point.

Comment: Does your MySQL allows connections from all the worker nodes, were you able to test mysql connectivity from all the worker nodes ?

Comment: Yes...I confirmed that every  node is able to access the database.

Answer (score 0):

This is a permissions issue: notice the UserGroupInformation is flagged:

```
    `at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:164`2)
```

What kind of security issue?  It is not clear from the Stacktrace. Is your code doing any HDFS?  Or what else that would trigger a security check?

Comment: Code reading structured data from hdfs directory and applying map reduce job and persisting data to the mysql database.

Comment: You need to look more closely at what is happening at the particular moment that the exception occurred: your comment indicates you are not clear on that.  You could start with hdfs and yarn: make sure the users accessing hdfs and running yarn have write permissions to local temp directories and that mysql user(s) are not being used to access hdfs (will get errors).